# JAVA Interfaces, Lists, and Instance Variables Not In Correct Positions

Tags: java, interface

Firstly, I have an interface as follows

```
interface Interface {
    void add(Object x);
    void delete(Object x);
    void print(Object x);
    void print();
}
```

Easy enough, so now I got this class that implements it called Employees and my main class that is called Driver.

Employees need a variable that assigns: first name, last name, department, and salary. Let's say three employees are entered and assigned the needed variables:

Abraham Little MANAGEMENT 1000

Maria Washington IT 2500

Gertrude Bush CUSTOMERSERVICE 500

```
public class Employees implements Interface {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String department;
    private String salary;
    List<Object> Employees = new ArrayList();
    
    public Employees () {
        this.firstName = null;
        this.lastName = null;
        this.department= null;
        this.salary= null;
    }
    public Player(String firstName, String lastName, String department, String salary) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.department = department;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
//This goes on with one's usual setFirstName(), setLastName(), etc. and the get.firstName(), getLastName(), etc. 

    @Override
    public void add(Object x) throws RuntimeException {
        Employees.add(x);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Object x) throws RuntimeException {
        Employees.remove(x);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String print() {
        return this.getFirstName() + 
                " " + this.getLastName() + 
                " " + this.getDepartment() + 
                " " + this.getSalary();
    }

    @Override
    public void print(Object x) throws RuntimeException {
        int count = 0;      
        while (Employees.size() > count) {
            System.out.println(Employees.get(count));
            count++;
      }
    }
    
}
```

Finally in Driver.java I have the following:

```
public class Driver { 
    public final String CUSTOMERSERVICE = "Customer Service";
    public final String IT = "IT";
    public final String MANAGEMENT = "Management";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employees employees = new Employees();
        //Create an employee
        Employees employee1= new Employees();
        employee1.setFirstName("Abraham");
        employee1.setLastName("Little");
        employee1.setDepartment(MANAGEMENT);
        employee1.setSalary("$1000");
        employees.add(employee1);
        //Repeat for all three employees
        employees.print(employees);
```

Works like a charm - problem is, apparently its not right. The feedback I got regarding this is: Employee instance variables should have been declared as a collection like ArrayList or LinkedList but not as String. That collection should be the only collection needed in the program. You did not create an interface for the constances specified (That'd be the String constants for the departments).

So exactly what does that mean? I figure the constants probably can just be moved to the interface, but then the main method doesn't get the constants, I think. Any way to clean this up and make it more presentable and fix the issues I was given?

Comment: hi, do you want to have a `List<Employee>` collection?

Comment: `public Player`? This wouldn't compile with that in there. Rather than an `Employees` object, you likely wanted an `Employee` object (since you are representing a single employee). From there, you could add them to some collection (e.g. a `List<Employee>`). Naming your interface as `Interface` is also not helpful to anyone (including you): It should describe what functionality it is bringing (it looks like it tried to supplement `List`). The departments could be well-represented using something like `public enum Department { MANAGEMENT, IT, CS, ... ; }`

Comment: He's asking you to separate `Employee` from `Employees`. The former should manage names, salary, etc,  for one employee, while the latter should manage one list of employees

Comment: also your print() is void in your interface but returns a String in your override

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really provide enough info to say, but the intent is probably to have you implement a container of employee objects. You have ingredients of this. They're just assembled in an off-beat way.

Did you invent the interface or was it given to you? It's bad. In early days of teaching you to program, it may make some kind of sense as an introduction. Later it can be improved. If you chose it yourself, go study more to improve it. Hint: `Object` is almost never used or needed in modern Java code.

```java
/** A silly container of anything.  */
class Container implements Interface {
  private List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();

  @Override
  public void add(Object x) {
    objects.add(x);
  }

  @Override
  public void delete(Object x) {
    objects.remove(x); 
  }
    
  @Override
  public String print() {
    objects.forEach(this::print);
  }

  @Override
  public void print(Object x) {
    System.out.println(x.toString());
  }
}

/** An immutable employee. */
class Employee {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String department;
  private String salary;

  Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String department, String salary) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    ...
  }
  ... getters (no setters)
  
  @Override
  public toString() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName + " " + department + " " + salary;
  }

  // Remove will work better if you also override equals()
}

class Runner {
  Container c = new Container();

  c.add(new Employee("Abraham", "Little", "management", "10000"));
  c.add(new Employee(...) );

  c.print();
}
```